# How to access a Cassandra docker volume in a new container?

Tags: docker, cassandra

After update my Cassandra docker container it raised the following error:

CassandraDaemon.java:911 - Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Cannot change the number of tokens from 256 to 16

I am using cassandra:latest image, and probably its updated its version, and after that the server shutdown every time I try to run it again. Any thoughts?

Comment: Tie yourself to a specific version and not use latest - the num_tokens value can not be changed on an existing node.

Answer (score 0):

The user asked the same question on https://community.datastax.com/questions/13536/ and I'm re-posting my answer here.

---

We do not recommend updating a Cassandra container to a newer version. Cassandra 4.0+ is pre-configured with [a new default of 16 virtual nodes](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0.0/NEWS.txt#L281-L288) ([CASSANDRA-13701](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13701)):

```
num_tokens: 16
```

Older versions of Cassandra had a default of 256. It is not possible to change the number of tokens allocated to a node once Cassandra has joined a cluster (even for single-node clusters). As you have already discovered, changing the allocated tokens will prevent Cassandra from starting.

You will need to edit the `cassandra.yaml` in order to allow Cassandra to start. Provided you named your container `cassandra`:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE      COMMAND  CREATED  STATUS  PORTS              NAMES
788db79a03d3  cassandra  ...      ...      Up      7000-7001/tcp,...  cassandra
```

you can view the cassandra container's configuration with:

```
$ docker inspect cassandra
```

and you will see that the configuration directory is set to:

```
                "CASSANDRA_CONF=/etc/cassandra",
```

Make a local copy of the configuration file:

```
$ docker cp cassandra:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml .
```

Edit your local copy then copy the modified version to the the container with:

```
$ docker cp cassandra.yaml cassandra:/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Cassandra allow the min token number is 256, so just modify num_tokens to 256 or higher value in cassandra.yaml, then restart Cassandra